# Gulp: Write a date in a CSS file to the generation of the latter

Tags: gulp

I try to reproduce in Gulp something I could do with Grunt: Write a date to file the generation of the latter (Stylus -> CSS or Jade -> html).

Here's what I did with Grunt (with grunt-banner):

```
// *.Gruntfile.js
<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd H:MM:ss") %>
```

How under Gulp? And above all, what use plugin Gulp (I have not yet found equivalent to [grunt-banner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-banner)...)?

EDIT :

I looked toward gulp-header, and then I finally decided to gulp-replace. Indeed the first place banners in the header files but my goal was to replace existing information.

Example :

```
// Gulpfile.js

var pkg = require('./package.json'),
rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('templates', function() {
  return gulp
    .src(source + '/Styles/Header.styl')
    .pipe(replace(/@-name .*\n/g, '@-name         ' + pkg.name + '\n'))
    .pipe(replace(/@-description .*\n/g, '@-description  ' + pkg.description + '\n'))
    .pipe(replace(/@-version .*\n/g, '@-version      ' + pkg.version + '\n'))
    .pipe(replace(/@-author .*\n/g, '@-author       ' + pkg.author + '\n'))
    .pipe(replace(/@-homepage .*\n/g, '@-homepage     ' + pkg.homepage + '\n'))
    .pipe(replace(/@-license .*\n/g, '@-license      ' + pkg.license + '\n'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(source + '/Styles'))
});
```

But I still do not know how to put a date modified as under Grunt ...

Comment: Maybe this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-transform-head

Comment: I answer my own question because I think I found the plugin I need: [gulp-header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-header)

Comment: Yep, that works too :) Can you actually write out an answer and accept it so this QA is marked as answered and useful for others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, I found:

```
var versionDate = new Date(); // javascript, just
```

Moved in the context it gives:

```
gulp.task('templates', function() {
  return gulp
    .src(source + '/Styles/Header.styl')
    .pipe(replace(/@name .*\n/g, '@name         ' + pkg.name + '\n'))
    .pipe(replace(/@description .*\n/g, '@description  ' + pkg.description + '\n'))
    .pipe(replace(/@version .*\n/g, '@version      ' + pkg.version + '\n'))
    .pipe(replace(/@lastmodified .*\n/g, '@lastmodified ' + versionDate + '\n'))
    .pipe(replace(/@author .*\n/g, '@author       ' + pkg.author + '\n'))
    .pipe(replace(/@homepage .*\n/g, '@homepage     ' + pkg.homepage + '\n'))
    .pipe(replace(/@license .*\n/g, '@license      ' + pkg.license + '\n'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(source + '/Styles'))
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I took over the approach including time setting: https://gist.github.com/jolution/9b2abbd53a326b8f1b2a13403f12e16f#file-gulpfile-js-L293

Answer (score 0):

Alternativ:

```
var headerComment = require('gulp-header-comment');
```

and in pipe:

```
.pipe(headerComment(`Generated on: <%= moment().format('DD.MM.YY') %>`))
```

[Manual gulp-header-comment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-header-comment)

[Example Gulp 4 File](https://gist.github.com/JulianKasimir/dbb51c70befc761f638dc815e6e4d1ea)